# Identify outermost call to recursive parser

Tags: python, pyparsing

I need some code to be run only in the outermost call to a recursive parser but can't think of a way to do this with pyparsing. Here is my code:

```
from pyparsing import *
from itertools import count

L_PAR, R_PAR, = map(Suppress, '()')


def process_stmt(counter):
    """Closure counts up when nesting occurs"""

    def parse_action(tokens):
        for t in tokens:
            t["count"] = next(counter)
            # if not outermost:
            t["outermost"] = False

            # if outermost:
            #     t["outermost"] = True

    return parse_action


def outermost_true(tokens):
    tokens['outermost'] = True
    tokens['other'] = True


counter = count(0)
OR_stmt = Forward()
AND_stmt = Group(OneOrMore(Word("XYZ", exact=3)
                           ^ OR_stmt))("AND*")
AND_stmt.setParseAction(process_stmt(counter))
OR_stmt <<= Group(L_PAR
                  + OneOrMore(AND_stmt)
                  + R_PAR)("OR*")
OR_stmt.setParseAction(process_stmt(counter))
AND_stmt.addParseAction(outermost_true)

data = "(XXXYYY)ZZZ"

AND_stmt.runTests(data)
```

which produces the following result

```
(XXXYYY)ZZZ
[[[['XXX', 'YYY']], 'ZZZ']]
- AND: [[[['XXX', 'YYY']], 'ZZZ']]
  [0]:
    [[['XXX', 'YYY']], 'ZZZ']
    - OR: [[['XXX', 'YYY']]]
      [0]:
        [['XXX', 'YYY']]
        - AND: [['XXX', 'YYY']]
          [0]:
            ['XXX', 'YYY']
            - count: 0
            - outermost: False
        - count: 1
        - other: True
        - outermost: False
    - count: 2
    - outermost: False
- other: True
- outermost: True
```

How can the outermost `outermost` attribute be set to `True`?

Comment: What happens if you add `tokens["outermost"] = True` to your parse action? This will set each ParseResults 'outermost' to True until it is encapsulated into another ParseAction, which will set it to False. The outermost ParseAction will not have this happen to it, so the setting to True will be retained.

Comment: That appears to work. But I don't understand why it works. My understanding is that actions are executed in the order they are added. The expected result is that _outermost_ is set to False by the _setParseAction_, then reset to True by _addParseAction_. What am I missing here?

Comment: The approach does something in each call, whereas the question is if it can be made so that it is only executed in the outermost call.

Comment: It isn't the order of parse actions that matters here, it is the order of the parse execution (plus, I don't see where there is a call to `addParseAction`-???). Contrary to @goodahn's comment, you are doing bottom-up parsing, so when each level's parse actions run, they set their level to "I am the outermost" and all lower levels to "I am not the outermost". When the top level is parsed, there is no higher level to set it to "not the outermost", so it remains at "I am the outermost".

Comment: Or create an `outermost = Forward()`, add a parse action to that to assign 'outermost' to True, do `outermost <<= AND_stmt`, and then use `outermost` to do your parsing instead of `AND_stmt`.

Comment: I think that I may have misunderstood. I understood your first comment to mean to add a parse action, which what is now in the updated question. It indeed has the effect that the outermost `outermost` is set to `True` while all others are `False`. It now dawned on me that `outermost` is manipulated in both outer and inner calls by means of `tokens` and `t`, although the mechanism is still unclear to me. I have tried to add `tokens['outermost'] = True` instead of using `addParseAction` and the result is indeed the same. Regarding using `Forward` it looks interesing. I'll have a look at that.

Comment: Is it correct to deduct that the parsing is bottom-up by the counter starting to count from the innermost call?

Comment: Adding as a separate parse action muddies the waters, partly because you added it to `AND_stmt` and the original parse action was on `OR_stmt`. Go back and simplify by using just one parse action, which sets the `outermost` to True on the current level of tokens, and clears `outermost` on all lower level tokens. And your deduction is correct (the proper verb form is "deduce", btw).

Answer (score 0):

I think I misunderstood your intention, when I saw that you were setting `outermost` to `True` or `False` in `process_stmt`. Rereading your question, you wanted *code to be run only in the outermost call to a recursive parser*. The solution is as I guessed in my comment, to create an outer `Forward` container and attach the parse action to that. Here is your code with all the intermediate calls to `process_stmt` removed, and just a single call to the outermost level in the containing `Forward`:

```
counter = count(0)
OR_stmt = Forward()
AND_stmt = Group(OneOrMore(Word("XYZ", exact=3)
                           ^ OR_stmt))("AND*")
OR_stmt <<= Group(L_PAR
                  + OneOrMore(AND_stmt)
                  + R_PAR)("OR*")
outermost = Forward()
outermost <<= AND_stmt
outermost.addParseAction(outermost_true)

data = "(XXXYYY)ZZZ"

outermost.runTests(data)
```

which gives:

```
(XXXYYY)ZZZ
[[[['XXX', 'YYY']], 'ZZZ']]
- AND: [[[['XXX', 'YYY']], 'ZZZ']]
  [0]:
    [[['XXX', 'YYY']], 'ZZZ']
    - OR: [[['XXX', 'YYY']]]
      [0]:
        [['XXX', 'YYY']]
        - AND: [['XXX', 'YYY']]
          [0]:
            ['XXX', 'YYY']
- other: True
- outermost: True
```

If you still want to have a parse action that is called for every level of your hierarchy, I modified process_stmt to print its progress as it gets called each time:

```
def process_stmt(counter):
    """Closure counts up when nesting occurs"""

    def parse_action(tokens):
        for t in tokens:
            t["count"] = next(counter)
            # t["outermost"] = False
            t["outermost"] = (False, "used to be {!r}".format(t.outermost))

        tokens['outermost'] = True

        print(tokens.dump())
        print()
    return parse_action
```

Showing these intermediate steps - better able to visualize how each call resets the inner level `outermost` to False, and its own outermost level to True

```
[['XXX', 'YYY']]
- AND: [['XXX', 'YYY']]
  [0]:
    ['XXX', 'YYY']
    - count: 0
    - outermost: (False, "used to be ''")
- outermost: True

[[['XXX', 'YYY']]]
- OR: [[['XXX', 'YYY']]]
  [0]:
    [['XXX', 'YYY']]
    - AND: [['XXX', 'YYY']]
      [0]:
        ['XXX', 'YYY']
        - count: 0
        - outermost: (False, "used to be ''")
    - count: 1
    - outermost: (False, 'used to be True')
- outermost: True

[[[['XXX', 'YYY']], 'ZZZ']]
- AND: [[[['XXX', 'YYY']], 'ZZZ']]
  [0]:
    [[['XXX', 'YYY']], 'ZZZ']
    - OR: [[['XXX', 'YYY']]]
      [0]:
        [['XXX', 'YYY']]
        - AND: [['XXX', 'YYY']]
          [0]:
            ['XXX', 'YYY']
            - count: 0
            - outermost: (False, "used to be ''")
        - count: 1
        - outermost: (False, 'used to be True')
    - count: 2
    - outermost: (False, 'used to be True')
- outermost: True
```